# Algorithm for sorting arrays of arrays

Tags: sorting, search-algorithms

I have a problem where I need to sort array of arrays.

For A being a array  arrays (a1,a2,a3,...an)

were each a = {0...d} d=fixed number of elements.

*The assumption all sublists will have fixed number & same of elements n. *sublists are already sorted from least to greatest

For example A = [{-2,-1,3},{-1,-2,INT_MAX},{1,2,5},{-50,10,75},{INT_MIN,11,65}], how this be sorted?

1. Should I consider the range as sorting criteria = MAX-MIN So [{-2,-1,3} range will have a range of 5 , and so on then I will sort each list on the increasing range?

Or, any ideas?

After sorting search will be easy, but how will i deal with duplicates.

For example, if i want to find -2 ,it occurs in both {-2,-1,3},{-1,-2,INT_MAX}.

The above problem is simplification of multiple binary trees that I have , for which I know their min and max node values, but I want to know which tree to start the search in.

Please just suggest algorithms efficient O(N log N) for sort & O(log N) for search, no need for implementation.

Thanks again.

Comment: So you want to find all occurrences of an element in all lists?

Comment: If that is the case I would propose just merging all binary trees and storing for each node in which lists the element occurred or using an interval tree where the nodes are your binary trees (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#With_a_point).

Comment: You seem to be using $n$ for the number of ("element") arrays/length or "top" array as well as for the `fixed number of elements` of `each a`. If both counts are to be identical, I'd prefer that stated unmistakably. If not, I find use of the same symbol for different quantities irritating.

Comment: Please clarify *in the question*: Does `sublists are already sorted` mean their elements are ordered to begin with? What about [dictionary order](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order)?

Comment: (Overall, `trees that I have, for which I know their min and max node values, but I want to know which tree to start the search in` makes this question look an [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/).)

Comment: @plshelp, yes how ever i want only access trees that may have that value, obvioudly based on min & max range. So if my query point falls with a tree with a min<=query_point<=max, then thats the tree that should be searched. So how do I get a list of appropriate trees?I will need to search taking into account both min & max.

Comment: @greybeard, No, but will always know the min & max of each sublist. Tree or sublist at times maybe sorted.

Comment: @greybeard,  fixed the notation. Apologies. n = number of sublists & d is elements per each list. d is fixed number across all lists.

Comment: @cyber101 are you allowed to use another data structure like an interval tree (which would find every BST which could contain the element) or only allowed to use the list and searches and sorting?

Comment: @plshelp, i used example of lists for simplicity. In reality, i will have many independent trees that are the same size. I just want to search trees that may have my query point rather searching all trees. My tree data structure will have attributes root,current_node_count,min_node_val,max_node_val. Obviously the root will have left,right pointers and a val field but that not relevant.

Comment: Ok if you have multiple queries interval trees are the way to go. There several tutorial on the web about them. You can apply them by regarding your search trees as intervals (min val is the left boundary max val is the right boundary) after you constructed such a tree you can use the following algo to find all intervals/BST that could contain your value: (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#With_a_point). Wikipedia also explains how to construct such a tree but a simple google search for interval tree will reveal many other tutorials.